# Library problem in an executable with Raspberry Pi5 (No such file or directory problem)

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi, gnu

[Screenshot via Raspberry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9sMi.jpg)

I want to transfer a software that is actively running on Raspberry 2 to Raspberry 5. In this migration process, I copied all the files to RP5. However, when I run it on RP5, even though I take a screenshot on localhost, my other codes do not work because I cannot run my file named 'gateway'. This gateway file is an executable file. As can be seen in the photo below, the libraries required for the gateway are written. When I try to run this file, I get the error 'No such file or directory' and when I run "ldd gateway" it says 'not a dynamic executable'. By running this file, I run c and c++ codes. What methods should I try to solve this error I am currently receiving? How can I install the libraries I view with "readelf"?

```
eos@raspberrypi:~ $ cd /eos-gateway
eos@raspberrypi:/eos-gateway $ readelf -d gateway

Dynamic section at offset 0x1af188 contains 35 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libcaf_io.so.0.14.0]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libcaf_core.so.0.14.0]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [librf24-bcm.so.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libmysqlcppconn.so.7]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libboost_system.so.1.55.0]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libcrypto.so.1.0.0]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x0000000f (RPATH)                      Library rpath: [/usr/local/lib]
 0x0000000c (INIT)                       0x24358
 0x0000000d (FINI)                       0x178d80
 0x00000019 (INIT_ARRAY)                 0x1cf12c
 0x0000001b (INIT_ARRAYSZ)               84 (bytes)
 0x0000001a (FINI_ARRAY)                 0x1cf180
 0x0000001c (FINI_ARRAYSZ)               4 (bytes)
 0x6ffffef5 (GNU_HASH)                   0x10194
 0x00000005 (STRTAB)                     0x14f64
 0x00000006 (SYMTAB)                     0x11ac4
 0x0000000a (STRSZ)                      57104 (bytes)
 0x0000000b (SYMENT)                     16 (bytes)
 0x00000015 (DEBUG)                      0x0
 0x00000003 (PLTGOT)                     0x1cf2c8
 0x00000002 (PLTRELSZ)                   2880 (bytes)
 0x00000014 (PLTREL)                     REL
 0x00000017 (JMPREL)                     0x23818
 0x00000011 (REL)                        0x236b8
 0x00000012 (RELSZ)                      352 (bytes)
 0x00000013 (RELENT)                     8 (bytes)
 0x6ffffffe (VERNEED)                    0x23508
 0x6fffffff (VERNEEDNUM)                 6
 0x6ffffff0 (VERSYM)                     0x22e74
 0x00000000 (NULL)                       0x0
eos@raspberrypi:/eos-gateway $ sudo ./gateway
sudo: unable to execute ./gateway: No such file or directory
eos@raspberrypi:/eos-gateway $ file gateway
gateway: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=5d922572a7f8a45905671e08c5221ec4a1f9ee4f, with debug_info, not stripped
eos@raspberrypi:/eos-gateway $ ldd gateway
    not a dynamic executable
eos@raspberrypi:/eos-gateway $ ls
all.log  gateway  last.log  lib  Makefile  obj  src  testcomm
```

Comment: Have you tried recompiling rather than copying? Your Pi 5 might be 64-bit, and the Pi 2 is certainly 32-bit.

Comment: You don't "run C++ codes", you *compile* C++ code, or more generally, you *build* your executable as that is usually a multi-step process.

Comment: So how can I update 64 bit on RP5?

Comment: You'll need to rebuild your app.

Comment: There is a lot of code in the recompilation phase. All codes were written in 2016. How should I go about this? I've never had to compile old code before. Please share your experiences with me.

Comment: I cannot predict how to do this for some code I've never seen. Usually there's a build procedure (e.g. `make`, or CMake, or some other contraption) you use to make the executables. Check the documentation.